# Inactivity Checker in Typescript using Cordova and Ionic?

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have seen the npm package ng-idle but it does not work with ionic mobile apps. I have found this JavaScript code and changed it a bit to suit my project but I get the error this.router is undefined.

```
var timeoutID : any;

constructor(public router: Router ){

    //Checks for inactivity constantly
    this.setupInactivityChecker();
}

startTimer() {
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(this.goInactive, 5000);
  }
  
  resetTimer() {
      window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
      this.goActive();
  }
  
  goInactive() {
      // do something
       console.log('Ahhhh.. finally inactive again. Now I may rest -_-');
       this.router.navigate(['login-screen']);
  }
  
  goActive() {
      // do something
      console.log('Active again');
      this.startTimer();
  }
  
  setupInactivityChecker() {
    addEventListener("mousemove", this.resetTimer(), true);
    addEventListener("mousedown", this.resetTimer(), true);
    addEventListener("keypress", this.resetTimer(), true);
    addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", this.resetTimer(), true);
    addEventListener("mousewheel", this.resetTimer(), true);
    addEventListener("touchmove", this.resetTimer(), true);
    addEventListener("MSPointerMove", this.resetTimer(), true);
  
    this.startTimer();
  }
```

Also on a side note: Can anyone explain why I can't use brackets in a handler? Like with:

```
timeoutID = window.setTimeout(this.goInactive, 5000);
```

I just want the app to log out when it has been idle for a certain amount of time so any links would be appreciated.

Ok guys so this is the version that works fine.

```
    let outsideRouter : any;
    var timeoutID : any;
    
    export class ScannerLogicService {

    constructor(private network: Network, private router: Router,public barcode: BarcodeScanner, public alertController: AlertController, private http: HttpClient, private dialog: Dialogs) {

        outsideRouter = router;
        setupInactivityChecker();

    }
    }

function startTimer() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive, 1800000);
}

function resetTimer() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    goActive();
}

function goInactive() {
     console.log('Ahhhh.. finally inactive again. Now I may rest -_-');
     outsideRouter.navigate(['login']);
}

function goActive() {
    console.log('Active again');
    startTimer();
}

function setupInactivityChecker() {
  addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, true);
  addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, true);
  addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, true);
  addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, true);
  addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, true);
  addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, true);
  addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, true);

  startTimer();
}
```

Notice that my functions are called outside of the class of my service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ionic Angular, using `@HostListener` is the best way to achieve what you re trying to do like so:

```
@HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
@HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
onEvent(event) {
    this.resetTimer();
}
```

then in your `constructor` or `ngOnInit()` you can call `this.startTime()`.

For your use case which is to check inactivity, you can write this code in your `app.component.ts` file which will listen for all the specified events in `AppComponent` and its child components, which for a regular Angular or Ionic app, will be the whole application.

You can learn more about `@HostListener` here: https://dzone.com/articles/what-are-hostbinding-and-hostlistener-in-angular